# How to stop reloading of View Controller after navigating back button in IOS

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, reload

I am working on an IOS app consisting Horizontal Scroll View containing buttons. I show only 3 items on scrollview at a time.When I click on any button on scrollview it goes to next view properly but when I return back to previous view the scrollview is reinitialise because of reloading of view.

```html
example :
values on scrollview are A B C D E F
at begining A B C are shown
when I scroll futher it shows B C D
Now if I selected C it goes further but after pressing back navigation the scrollview again shows A B C.... but rather it must show B C D
```

How can I stop reloading of viewcontroller after navigating back to previous view?

Comment: How and where is your scrollview instantiated? Are you returning back to the previous view controller by pressing the default back button in nav bar? If not, how are you doing that?

Comment: Please post some code? Cannot provide much help with the information you have provided.